# How should I define this variable?

Tags: c++

I have several header files `.h` and their corresponding `.cpp` files. Here suppose I have `part1.h` and `part2.h` for declaration. The corresponding `cpp` are `part1.cpp` and `part2.cpp` for definition the functions.

I also have a file with `main`. In this main function, I have a variable `float * change`. As its name, I will change the value of `change` and then call function `F` defined in `part1.cpp` and `G` in `part2.cpp`. The problem is  I cannot pass `change` as a parameter. 
So at first I plan to define it as a global variable. But then I found this variable always changes. But a global variable only can be defined once. So is there any method to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: THis variable always changes? What do you mean there?

Comment: @Deduplicator, Sorry for that. change=(float *)malloc(1024); 'Always changes' means `change[1]=10;` at first. But in the follows, there are `change[1]=100;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the variable as normal in one of your `.cpp` files

```
float* change;
```

Then in one of your header files, you can declare it:

```
extern float* change;
```

Now #include the header file wherever the global variable is used.

Comment: Hello. I use the `global.h` and I write something like `extern float* ptr`. And I define ptr in main function!!! I include "global.h" in every file I use it(part1.cpp;part1.h;main.cpp). But there is error `error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol`. Could you please tell me how should I solve it?

Comment: hello. I solved it. I have to do something like `float * ptr` outside the main function. Then the error gone. Is this right?

Comment: @Vivian Yes, that is correct. A global variable must be outside all functions. When you declare a variable in `main()`, it is local, not global.

Answer (score 1):

Declare in one of your headers

```
extern float * change;  // does not define the variable, but just that it exists somewhere
```

You can also declare this directly in `part1.cpp` and `part2.cpp` instead of a common header.  However if you'd later change something, float to double for example, you should not forget any of those declarations.

Remember Stroustrups famous quote:  "// global variable – avoid those where you can"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do get/set functions to get variable from whenever you want and you'd keep OOP encapsulation. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/107842/